# Zend framework 1 twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, frameworks

i was wondering if there is a way to implement twitter bootstrap into zend framework 1.12?
I'm not looking only for form decorators, is it possible to add full functionality of bootstrap of how to do this.Thanx.
**EDIT:**

**if it is impossible, than could you recommend a good frontend framework**